# Comparing List to List with a Twist

Tags: c#

I want to compare two List of different lengths and/or same length. The first list is considered the Original list. The 2nd list is the Updated list. The second list may be the same but ordered differently.

I would like to keep track of additions and subtractions from the list. If something was removed it could be added to a removed collection and vice versa.

Below is an example of each list with an input

```
Original List    Updated List
=============    ============
Jim              Tom
Tom              Mike
Mike             Harry
Sue              Sue
Kim              Roger
Roger
```

This is an desired output:

```
Addition List    Subtraction List
=============    ================
Harry            Jim
                 Kim
```

If you have Ideas I would be glad to hear them!

Comment: How about using a pair of Set and their Subset/Intersect capability?

Comment: The capital 'Twist' really through me off here. I was wondering what type of datastructure a 'List with a Twist' was. Too bad -- it sounded exciting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use LINQ.

```
var diff1 = List1.Except(List2);
var diff2 = List2.Except(List1);
```